# Unable to access kubernetes dashboard : no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I install the kubernetes-dashboard on a kubernetes cluster base on Redhat linux.

Everything seems to be fine

```
# kubectl get --namespace kube-system pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard-4236001524-m9uxm   1/1       Running   0          2h
```

except that when I try to access to the web interface

http://g-lsdp-kuber-master.rd.mydomain.fr:8080/ui

I'm redirected to to this new url

http://g-lsdp-kuber-master.rd.mydomain.fr:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/

and the result is :

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.17.0.2:9090: getsockopt: no route to host'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.2:9090/'
```

I don't know where to find a solution, I already try to add a dns

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d415363280aa gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-03-11-001     "/skydns"                38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           furious_ramanujan
12d3530c9f4d  gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11   "/kube2sky -v=10 -log"   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes
```

with the same result.

Comment: Do you have an ingress and service? Can you show those?

Comment: Make sure you have a pod network installed. (kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube)

Comment: I try to install pod network as you recommand but it seems to be not authorized    $ sudo kubectl apply -f weave-daemonset.yaml
    
    The DaemonSet "weave-net" is invalid.

    * spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged:    Forbidden: disallowed by policy
    * spec.template.spec.containers[1].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by policy

Comment: I suppose I haven't ingress (I don't what it is)

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? 'Ingress' means that you have rules set up to allow inbound traffic [as per the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#what-is-ingress).